# Find where insertion point is currently placed in textarea/contenteditable is

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

I'm currently trying to create a dynamic text area, though I'm facing an issue with some areas where I have to block the event from fulfilling itself, and I've come to a conclusion that I need to find out where the **insertion point** is in the current textarea or contenteditable divider.

I've used the events `keydown` and `keyup` in jQuery but they don't log when the click is made on the divider, and I wouldn't know what to look in the `event` object to find what I'm after.

For example, if I'm in an empty textarea and click on the textarea, it will return `0`, since it's at the beginning - and if I were to write text it would return numbers as more characters are inserted into the textarea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` properties from [`textarea`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement). For `contenteditable` element you can use [`window.getSelection()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection).

```js
$('#text1').on('keyup click', function() {
  console.log('Selection start :', $(this).prop('selectionStart'));
  console.log('Selection end :', $(this).prop('selectionEnd'));
});

$('#text2').on('keyup click', function() {
  console.log(window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startOffset);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="text1"></textarea>
<div id="text2" contenteditable>some text</div>
```

Comment: Would this work for `contenteditable`? That's my current target and I thought they would work with each other